# What is the difference between tostring() and tobytes() methods of array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Both the tostring() method and tobytes() method seem to work the same, what is the difference?

```
from array import array 
array1 = array('i',[1,2,3,4,5])
str1 = array1.tostring()
print(str1)
byt1 = array1.tobytes()
print(byt1)
```

Comment: What version of python are you using exactly?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, `tostring` they are both aliases to the same method, `tostring` was renamed to `tobytes` for the purposes fo clarity in Python 3.2, [as mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.tobytes)

`tostring` has been kept for backwards compatibility, but the use of `tostring` is deprecated.